# How to follow a cycle only once?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb

I'm a new ArangoDB user and I'm having a problem that I don't know how to solve it. I have a graph composed by over 340k nodes and over 430k links with cycles and I'm trying to find a path between A and B. I know for sure that in the path between those 2 nodes I will encounter loops so I used the option *followCycles*. As a query I use something:

`FOR target, unused, path IN 1..150 OUTBOUND "A" connected OPTIONS {followCycles: True, uniqueEdges: "none"}
  FILTER target._id == "B"
  LIMIT 1
  RETURN path`

IMO this query should return me that path between A and B also considering the loop. Unfortunately that query is not able to find the path and it runs "forever" because of the dimension of the graph.

Anyway, I have noticed that if I use an intermediate node I'm able to find the path. I did something like:

`FOR target, unused, path IN 1..150 OUTBOUND "A" connected OPTIONS {followCycles: True, uniqueEdges: "none"}
  FILTER target._id == "intermediate"
  LIMIT 1
  RETURN path`

`FOR target, unused, path IN 1..150 OUTBOUND "intermediate" connected OPTIONS {followCycles: True, uniqueEdges: "none"}
  FILTER target._id == "B"
  LIMIT 1
  RETURN path`
 
I suspect that because of the loops the value `150` is not enough, I tried also with `15000` but I had the same result.

Do you know if there is an option for saying to traverse a loop only once or anything else in order to avoid the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only looking for any path between `A` and `B` the following query should work for you.

```
FOR target, unused, path IN 1..150 OUTBOUND "myCollection/A" connected
OPTIONS {uniqueVertices: "global", bfs: true}
  FILTER target._id == "myCollection/B"
  LIMIT 1
  RETURN path
```

With `uniqueVertices: "global"` each vertex (node) is only visited once during the traversal. Which means loops are not followed.

With `bfs: true` you use the breadth-first algorithm. Which means the traversal first runs over all found vertices of depth 1 then 2 and so on. Using this allows you to find a path shorter by avoiding to follow a path until your max depth (150) is reached to realize that their is no connected path.

For more information about AQL graph traversal, you should take a look into the [docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html).

Comment: Thanks I also used followCycles